# Is there any way to know which c++ core function is called in tensorflow?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

I heard that tensorflow is wrapped with python and the core function is implemented as c++.
I wonder which core c++ function is called after Python code is called. Is there a way to know? The tensorflow profiler only provides information about the python function. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 levels of depth that you need to go through to get to C++ code: Python implementation, wrappers, and C++.

### In case it's an OP (like Conv / Matmul / ...)

First you need to trace what gets called by python implementation. If you're using some high level library utils like Keras, it may be quite hard. It's way easier if you're directly calling math operations in TF (like `nn.conv2d`).
Most of ops are implemented in `tensorflow/python/ops`. For example, function `nn.conv2d` is implemented in `tensorflow/python/ops/nn.ops.py`.

As you can see, this op (as most ops) delegate the work to `gen_nn_ops.conv2d.py`. There are auto-generated filed during build, so unless you're willing to inspect bazel files and build from source, you can't view this file.

Fortunately, it seems to me that there is a direct mapping between function available in `gen_` filed and ops defined in `.cc` files.

By investigating `tensorflow/core/ops/nn_ops.cc` you can find Registration of Conv Op

```
REGISTER_OP("Conv2D")
    .Input("input: T")
    .Input("filter: T")
    .Output("output: T")
    .Attr("T: {half, bfloat16, float, double}")
    .Attr("strides: list(int)")
    .Attr("use_cudnn_on_gpu: bool = true")
    .Attr(GetPaddingAttrStringWithExplicit())
    .Attr(GetExplicitPaddingsAttrString())
    .Attr(GetConvnetDataFormatAttrString())
    .Attr("dilations: list(int) = [1, 1, 1, 1]")
    .SetShapeFn(shape_inference::Conv2DShapeWithExplicitPadding);
```

Unfortunately, this macro only tells tensorflow that there is such operation as Conv2D, but it doesn't say anything about how it should run.

In tensorflow, Op specifies what needs to be done, but Kernel is the one that actually does the job. You can find kernels that can run a given op by looking for `REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER` macro. It is responsible for matching a kernel to an Op.
For conv2d, you can find one in `tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc`

```
#define REGISTER_CPU(T)                                         \
  REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(                                      \
      Name("Conv2D").Device(DEVICE_CPU).TypeConstraint<T>("T"), \
      Conv2DOp<CPUDevice, T>);

// If we're using the alternative GEMM-based implementation of Conv2D for the
// CPU implementation, don't register this EigenTensor-based version.
#if !defined(USE_GEMM_FOR_CONV)
TF_CALL_half(REGISTER_CPU);
TF_CALL_float(REGISTER_CPU);
TF_CALL_double(REGISTER_CPU);
#endif  // USE_GEMM_FOR_CONV
```

This finally brings us to what we were looking for. Kernels have compute method, so we're interested in Conv2DOp<CPUDevice, T>::Compute.
Here it is (defined in the same file):

```
  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Input tensor is of the following dimensions:
    // [ batch, in_rows, in_cols, in_depth ]
    const Tensor& input = context->input(0);

    // Input filter is of the following dimensions:
    // [ filter_rows, filter_cols, in_depth, out_depth]
    const Tensor& filter = context->input(1);

    Conv2DDimensions dimensions;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context,
                   ComputeConv2DDimension(params_, input, filter, &dimensions));

    TensorShape out_shape = ShapeFromFormat(
        params_.data_format, dimensions.batch, dimensions.out_rows,
        dimensions.out_cols, dimensions.out_depth);

    // Output tensor is of the following dimensions:
    // [ in_batch, out_rows, out_cols, out_depth ]
    Tensor* output = nullptr;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, out_shape, &output));
    
    ...  // Skipped for clarity

    if (params_.padding != EXPLICIT &&
        LaunchDeepConvOp<Device, T>::Run(
            context, input, filter, dimensions.batch, dimensions.input_rows,
            dimensions.input_cols, dimensions.in_depth, dimensions.filter_rows,
            dimensions.filter_cols, dimensions.pad_rows_before,
            dimensions.pad_cols_before, dimensions.out_rows,
            dimensions.out_cols, dimensions.out_depth, dimensions.dilation_rows,
            dimensions.dilation_cols, dimensions.stride_rows,
            dimensions.stride_cols, output, params_.data_format)) {
      return;
    }
    ...
```

This is the end of the journey. Some ops have actual implementation in this place. Conv2D is not very satisfying - it turns out it delegates the work to `LaunchDeepConvOp`. You can dig deeper if you need.

### In case it's not an Op

Ops are quite special in TF. Other code is linked to python by means of C API.

C api is available as `c_api.cc` and `c_api.h`. Header file declares C functions available to python. Source file (`.cc`) is a bridge between C and C++ - it defines C functions (or to be more precise, functions with C linkage) that call corresponding C++ functions. If you know the C function, it's pretty easy to trace which C++ function was called.

From Python, it usually looks like

```
# Import
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as c_api

...

# Usage
def get_all_registered_kernels():
  """Returns a KernelList proto of all registered kernels.
  """
  buf = c_api.TF_GetAllRegisteredKernels()
```

As you can see names are matching. Implementation of this wrapper is generated, so don't look for it.